# Matching partial filenames with the "**" pattern

Tags: bash, file, directory, glob

The documentation on the [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) bash option reads:

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match **all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories**. If
>   the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories
>   match.

That made me think that given a hierarchy like this:

```
└── dir1
    └── dir2
        └── dir3
            └── file.txt
```

I could match `file.txt` in this tree structure using a pattern like `**file*`. But it doesn't work:

```
ls **file*
ls: cannot access '**file*': No such file or directory
```

This works though:

```
ls **/file*
dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

I wonder if `**` is supposed to match *either* a file's directory or a full filename. Links to more precise documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: @anubhava No, with globstar enabled, it will match all directories recursively

Comment: @thatotherguy: But that is not the behavior I get in bash. `shopt -s globstar; mkdir adir; touch adir/afile; ls **afile` gives `ls: cannot access '**afile': No such file or directory`. However when I do `ls **/afile` then I get `adir/afile`

Comment: @anubhava Your comment was about `**` followed by `/` , which does behave like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), which handles the expansion of `**` the same way as Bash, seems more precise:

> If a "globstar" (`**`) is *alone in a path portion*, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.
>
> [.. The double-star character] is supported in the manner of bsdglob and bash 4.3, where `**` *only* has special significance if it is the only thing in a path part. That is, `a/**/b` will match `a/x/y/b`, but `a/**b` will not.

So `**` must be the only thing in a path part.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is correct, if a bit telegraphic. If globstar is set and `**` is used as part of a glob, the component of the pattern it appears in (components are the parts of the pattern delimited by <kbd>/</kbd> characters) will be matched against:

- directory paths with zero or more components
- filenames in the current context, if the globstar component is not followed with a <kbd>/</kbd>.

Note that `**/` will match the current directory (a path with zero components) even though the <kbd>/</kbd> does not appear to match anything.

If you wanted to match `*file*` in any subdirectory (recursively), you would use `**/*file*`. The `**/` would then match all directories and subdirectories (recursively), and in each one an attempt would be made to match `*file*` as a filename (including the name of a directory).